# Simplify percentage calculation c#

Tags: c#, decimal, percentage

I have this code, which I believe is self-explanatory (although ugly):

```
    public decimal Stat
    {
        get
        {
            if (Incorrect == 0)
                return 100;
            decimal x = (decimal)(Correct / Incorrect) / (decimal)(Correct + Incorrect) * 100;
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make this code prettier?

Comment: You can use the [?: conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), aka 'inline if'.

Comment: What are you trying to compute? The percentage correct?

Comment: I think readable code is pretty code.  The only thing I can think to make it more readable would be to put `(decimal)(Correct / Incorrect)` and `(decimal)(Correct + Incorrect) ` into temporary variables.  I find less going on in one line to be more readable.  Although if you find the code self-explanatory, then it's readable (and thus, I'd say, pretty).

Comment: Also if Correct and Incorrect are integers, this almost certainly contains a late conversion to decimal bug.

Comment: Not sure what you're calculating there...it should probably be: `return (decimal)Correct / (decimal)(Correct + Incorrect) * (decimal)100;`

Comment: yes, it's percentage. It's more import that everyone finds it readable (not just me). Correct and Incorrect are ints, yes. Thus, it's a bug? Could you tell me more about that?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't meant `decimal x = (decimal)(Correct) / (decimal)(Correct + Incorrect) * 100;`?

Comment: @Gusman, thanks for clearing that up. Too late at night to do programming now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can cast only one side of the division, or just multiply it by 100.0 at the beginning (then casing to decimal will not be needed).
2. You don't have to take care of the edge case of Incorrect == 0, because if it holds, then 100 will be returned (**100.0 * X / (X+0) equals 100.0)**

   ```
   public decimal Stat
   {
       get
       {
           return 100m * Correct / (Correct + Incorrect);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I do also agree that the ternary operator makes the code a bit messy in this case.

Comment: I edited my answer; I think that the if-else are not necessary here.

Comment: Result should always be 100 if Incorrect == 0, so this seems correct, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `100.0` is `double`, add suffix to turn it into `decimal`: `100m`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `decimal`, not `int` arithmetics. The easiest way is to start formula with decimal `100m`:

```
public decimal Stat
{
    get
    {
        return (Correct + Incorrect == 0)
          ? 100m
          : 100m * Correct / (Correct + Incorrect);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very neat solution. I like it!

Comment: Am i making a mess here? the `100m` value should be at the end right?

Comment: @Luis Filipe: `100m` should be at the *left* end: `100m` is of type `decimal` that's why `100m * Correct`, `100m * Correct / Incorrect` ... are `decimal` and we don't have *integer division* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two points,

1. A percentage correct would be `Correct * 100m / (Correct + Incorrect)`. You've divided by Incorrect again after this. I don't know why that is but it seems wrong.
2. The result of integer division is another integer. If Correct is 1 and Incorrect is 4 then the result of `Correct / Incorrect` is 0. Always convert to the floating point types before doing division.

I would rewrite this code like so,

```
public int Total => Correct + Incorrect;

// renamed "Stat"
public decimal PercentageCorrect => (Correct * 100m) / Total;
```

Total seems like a useful quantity. Let's just make it a property. Renaming "Stat" makes it obvious what it is. Just reading your code, I had to ask what "Stat" was because it was not obvious what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be:

```
public decimal Stat
{
    get
    {
        decimal Total = (decimal)(Correct + Incorrect);
        return (decimal)Correct / Total * 100.0M;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use 100.0M instead of casting.

Comment: @MegaTron There's no need for the `Incorrect == 0` check....try it out.